# How to assign a value to a variable using if else statements

Tags: javascript, variables

I am trying to assign a value to a variable using if else statements, but can't get it to work. Can somebody help me?
Or is there a more elegant way to achieve that?

```
(function(){
var func1 = function () {

if (field1 >= 1) && (field1 <= 2) {return "A";}
else if (field1 >= 3) && (field1 <= 4) { return "B"; }
else if (field1 >= 5) && (field1 <= 6) { return "C"; }
else {return "D";}
}

return func1;

})()
```

Comment: what's not working? why not just `if else`?

Comment: anytime you need a 1:1 pivot (input:output), use a simple LUT instead of nested conditionals or switching: `return ["","A","B","C"][field1]||"D";` you can also handle string inputs with an object: `return {A:1,B:2,C:3}[key]||4;` - look ma, no quotes!

Comment: I have multiple conditions, just edited my question with some more code

Comment: @TimodeVries: if the range actually isn't that "rangy/sparse", just repeat index values in the LUT: `["","A","A","B","B","C","C"][field1]||"D";` this runs much faster and you can re-use the "truth table" in other functions (or modify it dynamically) instead of maintaining brittle forks.

Comment: "Elegance" is in the eye of the beholder. For instance, some might find @dandavis's code elegant; some might find it cryptic :). If you can define what you mean by elegance that can be objectively measured, that would keep the question on-topic.

Comment: The error in your console should point to you to why it is not working

Comment: the overloaded switch is another option to evaluate multiple conditionals in a simpler syntax than IFs: `switch(true){ case a>1 && a<3: return 1; case a>2 && a<4: return 2 ... }`

Comment: Parentheses are wrong.  Instead of `if (xxx) && (yyy)` you should write `if (xxx && yyy)`

Answer (score 0):

It works if you define `field1`, remove extra parenthesis in if conditions and call your `func1` function somewhere

```js
(function() {
  var func1 = function() {
    // You should define field1
    var field1 = 5;

    if (field1 >= 1 && field1 <= 2) {
      return "A";
    }
    if (field1 >= 3 && field1 <= 4) {
      return "B";
    } 
    if (field1 >= 5 && field1 <= 6) {
      return "C";
    }
    
    return "D";
  }
  // You should call your function for it to actually return something
  console.log(func1())

  return func1;
})()
```

Comment: None of the `else` are necessary.

Comment: I've removed the useless `else`s. I don't know about the self invoking function, but it may be useful in the context of usage of this code.

Answer (score 0):

With `Math.floor()`.

*Make* every number between **a** and **b** with `Math.floor()` to **a**.

### Example

```js
const val = 3.3;

// arr[0] -> 1 <= val < 2
// arr[1] -> 2 <= val < 3
// arr[2] -> 3 <= val < 4
// ...
const arr = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];

function getResult(val) {
  const floored = Math.floor(val);
  // Index starts with 0 -> floored - 1 
  return arr[floored - 1] ||  "G";
}

console.log(getResult(val));
```